# How to gain an Access Token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am lost, I have no idea what should I do to get the access token. This is the code that I have tried, please help, please!

This is for Oauth2.0 token, and the API is Ocotoparse.

```
from octoparse import Octoparse as oct 
import requests
host='https://advancedapi.octoparse.com/token'
url=host+'username={onlyfiii}&password={19970909huy}&grant_type=password'

r=requests.post(url)

username='onlyfiii'
password='19970909huy'
{
    "access_token": "ABCD1234",      
    "token_type": "bearer",     
    "expires_in": 86399,  
    "refresh_token": "refresh_token" 
}
```

Comment: That depends on a lot of things. The API you want an OAuth token from, the authorization flow you want to use, etc.

Comment: This should be an Oauth2.0 Token, and the API is Ocotoparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that's not your real password, if it is, change it *immediately*.

You need to send the request parameter as a form encoded POST request body, not as url parameters.

```py
import requests
import json

url = 'https://advancedapi.octoparse.com/token'
payload = {
  'username': 'onlyfiii', 
  'password': '19970909huy', 
  'grant_type': 'password',
}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
json_response = json.loads(r.text)
access_token = json_response['access_token']
```

See the [API docs](http://advancedapi.octoparse.com/help#_get_token):

> #### Request Content Type
>
> `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: No, that's not a real password, I made it up, thanks though.

Comment: Thanks!IT WORKED!